# Is there a polynomial $g(x)$ such that $p \circ f=g \circ p$, where $f(x)=9x+30x^3+27x^5+9x^7+{{x}^{9}}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory, polynomials, commutative-algebra

Let us consider a polynomial $f(x)=9x+30x^3+27x^5+9x^7+{{x}^{9}}$ over a field of characteristic $0$.

Set $p(x)=x^nh(x), n \geq 1$, where $h(x)$ can be any rational function.

I am trying to find out another polynomials $g(x)$ such that $p \circ f=g \circ p$. One more information, for any zero $\alpha$ of $f(x)$, $~~p(\alpha)$ is a root of $g(x)$.

If $h(x)=1$, then we need find a $g(x)$ such that $(f(x))^n=g(x^n)$.

I exclude the case $f = g, n=1$.

I have found the roots of $f(x)$ [here](https://www.mathportal.org/log/pdfCalculators/Result72841.pdf) in decimal form.

I thing this gives a hints about $g(x)$ because $f(\alpha)=0 \Rightarrow f(p(\alpha))=0$.

**Edit:** sorry for multiple edits but I hope this is the final one

Comment: What about $g = h = f$ ? Or $h = 0$ and $g(0)=0$ ? Also why call $p$ the only map that does not need be a polynomial.

Comment: @Gribouillis, thanks but these are trivial and will serve my purpose. I should have mentioned it  before. I edited the question

Comment: Then what makes a solution non trivial? What about $h = f\circ f$ and $g=f$ ?

Comment: @Gribouillis, please look at the edited question. I mentioned $f \neq g \neq p$

Comment: With the new version of the question, there is a term $x^{n+2}$ in $f(x)^n$, but $g(x^n)$ has only monomials of the form $x^{k n}$. It implies that $2$ is a multiple of $n$, hence $n$ can be only 1 or 2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$
\begin{array}{rcl}
p(x)&=&9x,\\
g(x)&=&\displaystyle \frac{x^9}{43046721}+\frac{x^7}{59049}+\frac{x^5}{243}+\frac{10 x^3}{27}+9 x.
\end{array}
$$

**Upd.** For the new version
$$
\begin{array}{rcl}
p(x)&=&x^2,\\
g(x)&=&x (x+3)^2 \left(x (x+3)^2+3\right)^2;
\end{array}
$$

$$
\begin{array}{rcl}
p(x)&=&x^4+4 x^2,\\
g(x)&=&x (x+3)^2 \left(x (x+3)^2+3\right)^2.
\end{array}
$$

$$
\begin{array}{rcl}
p(x)&=&x^2 \left(x^2+3\right)^2,\\
g(x)&=&x (x+3)^2 \left(x (x+3)^2+3\right)^2.
\end{array}
$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I appreciate it.

Comment: But I am looking for such $p(x)$ which has at least one multiple root, e.g., of the form $p(x)=cx^n$ or $p(x)=\frac{cx^n}{1+x}$, $p$ can be any function satisfying above but at least one multiple root. Please look at the edited question. Can you help with such one ?

Comment: I really appreciate it. The beautiful answer. May I know how did you find those ?

Comment: @learner By direct calculations with CAS.

Comment: fine. Now can you help me to find a polynomial whose first degree coefficient is not a multiple of $3$ and that commutes with $g(x)$, you obtained above ? The trivial one the polynomial $x$

Comment: @learner $x=0$ wouldn't be a multiple root then.

Comment: @learner btw the forms $f(x)= x \left(x^2+3\right) \left(x^2 \left(x^2+3\right)^2+3\right)$ and $g(x) =x (x+3)^2 \left(x (x+3)^2+3\right)^2$ seems to be too much alike for a coincidence.
A recursive built up  in both cases: $f_{n+1}=f_n(3+f_n^2)$ and $g_{n+1}=g_n(3+g_n)^2$, $f_0=g_0=x$.

Comment: Perhaps I could not write clearly. I said I want a polynomial $r(x)=ax+\cdots$ such that r(x) commutes with g(x) and gcd$(a,3)=1$

Comment: @learner Does commutes with $g$  mean $r \circ g=g \circ r$?

Comment: yes exactly. Can you help me with that ? Though the polynomial $g(x)$ is big.

Comment: in case it becomes difficult to answer the previous comment, then there is an alternate way that will help me. Can you find a $g(x)$ $(\neq f^{\circ n})$ (as in your answer) if $f(x)=5x+5x^2+x^5$ ? That is I am just replacing the previous $f(x)$ in my question and keeping others same. Thanks